# Placing @media tag within class to simplify and avoid repetition

Tags: html, css

For full css/html excerpt please see: https://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/jbnsd9hc/1/

I have the following specific 2 definitions:

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 120px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: -50px;
    }
}
```

I would like to refactor the code to be more elegant. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
     /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 120px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: -50px;
}
}
```

**Clarification: How can I rewrite the above in order to not be repetitive?**

Comment: What is the question, exactly? Currently it reads as "I tried this invalid method of CSS styling and it didn't work."

Comment: You are nesting CSS rules. You can't do that. It's invalid.

Comment: @Santi  How can I rewrite the above in order to not be repetitive?I made an invalid example but that's the question. Mixins?

Comment: SASS/SCSS you can next media queries inside the declaration

Comment: It's also worth noting that you only need to add the properties that you want to change, not the *whole lot*

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos — CSS doesn't support Mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add my 2 cents worth, here's an example of your options:

**CSS:**

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

*Anything* you wish to change on a different resolution is changed in the media query **not** every property:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .dropdown-content {
        right: -50px;
    }
}
```

**SASS/SCSS:**

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    @media(min-width: 480px){
        right: -50px;
    }

    @media(min-width: 768px){
        right: -25px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Validate, validate, validate](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). You simply can't do that in CSS. A rule-set cannot contain a media query.

You *can* do it using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which can then convert it to CSS afterwards.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, so +1 as this is as simple as it gets

Answer (score 0):

You may simply cut out the repetitions. Just maintain what is different:

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .dropdown-content {
        right: -50px;
    }
}
```